# PHP　case文

Tags: php, laravel

下記のコードを書きました。
しかし、$ageがnullの場合defaultを通らずに
case $age >= 20 && $age < 30:を通ってしまいます。
何か理由などわかる方いましたら、ご教授ください

```
$age = $this->employee_age;
switch ($age) {
    case $age >= 20 && $age < 30:
        $generation = 1;
        break;
    case $age >= 30 && $age < 40:
        $generation = 2;
        break;
    case $age >= 40 && $age < 50:
        $generation = 3;
        break;
    case $age >= 50 && $age < 60:
        $generation = 4;
        break;
    case $age >= 60 && $age < 70:
        $generation = 5;
        break;
    case $age >= 70:
        $generation = 6;
        break;
    default:
        $generation = null;
        break;
}
```

Comment: `switch ($age)` ではなく `switch (true)` とします。前回の質問に対する回答に記載した [PHP: switch](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/control-structures.switch.php) をご参照ください。

Answer (score 1):

別解。

```php
$age = $this->employee_age;
switch (true) {
    case $age < 20:
        $generation = null;
        break;
    case $age >= 70:
        $generation = 6;
        break;
    default:
        $generation = intdiv($age, 10) - 1;
}
```